# Joint compound turned brown when it dried

Tags: drywall

I applied mud to butt joints in my drywall but in a couple of small sections the mud turned brown when it dried. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is "brown"? Slightly beige? Chocolate? Please show a photo with a white reference.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the brown is.

It may be that there were improper nails or screws used that rusted from the moisture in the mud.  In that case the screws or nails should be replaced with the correct drywall rated products. Otherwise the rust will continue to reappear even through primer and paint.

Or you have contaminated drywall mud.  How badly is unknown.  Perhaps the whole lot needs to be  discarded.

Some more details about how old the mud is. How big a job you are doing. Were proper nails or screws used, (if you know). Extra info would get better answers.